# Push notification not delivered to my phone when app is not running?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with push notifications not showing when my application is not running. The problem is on my Huawei P9 phone but in emulator everything works fine. Notification does show when application is running and I have checked in Apps > MyApp > Notifications and push notifications are enabled. Why is that?

I guess the problem is that somehow I need to check some box somewhere to enable notifications when app is not running. Seeing this happening on my phone (and on my friend's) while on emulator everything works I figured I should have some checkbox in my settings activity for users to enable push notifications (even when application is not running)? How do I do that?

**UPDATE 1**

```
public class EventNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final String TAG = "EventNotifyService";

    public EventNotificationService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> messageData = remoteMessage.getData();

        if(messageData.containsKey("notification_type")) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(messageData.get("notification_type")) == 1){
                onEventNotification(remoteMessage);
            }

            else if (Integer.parseInt(messageData.get("notification_type")) == 2) {
                onReservationMessage(remoteMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onEventNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> event = remoteMessage.getData();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(EventActivity.EXTRA_EVENT_URL, "http://clzola.com/api/v1/event/show/public?id=" + Integer.parseInt((String)event.get("id")));

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText((String) event.get("title"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }


    private void onReservationMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    }
}
```

And code for sending notification from my server:

```
$requestBody = [
        "to" => "/topics/event_category_" . $event->event_category_id,
        "notification" => [
            "body" => $event->title,
            "title" => "New event created",
            "sound" => "default",
            "priority" => "high",
        ],
        "data" => [
            "notification_type" => 1,
            "id" => $event->id,
            "title" => $event->title,
        ]
    ];

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', [
        "headers" => [
            "Content-Type" => "application/json",
            "Authorization" => "key=" . env("FCM_SERVER_KEY"),
        ],
        "body" => json_encode($requestBody)
    ]);
```

Comment: Post your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet with settings activity, but for the my class that extends FirebaseMessagesService, it works fine as on the emulator same applications works without any flaws, except for real devices, push notifications does not show up only when app is not running @FerdousAhamed

Comment: Post your class that extends FirebaseMessagesService

Comment: Are you sending `notification` or `data` FCM?

Comment: FCM that has a `notification` payload is posted by the Google Play services app when you own app is not running. To ensure that the push message is always delivered to your `FirebaseMessagingService` *never* send the `notification` payload. Put everything you need to build the notification in the `data` payload.

Comment: Seems Ok. Add some logs into onEventNotification() to know the behavior when app is in background state.

Comment: @EugenPechanec but will notification show up when application is not running when I do not have 'notification' payload?

Comment: It will not, you'll have to show the notification yourself in your `EventNotificationService`. You're already doing that because the message is delivered to this class when your app is running. You just have to rewrite it so it doesn't use `remoteMessage.getNotification()`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec As I understand FCM guide, onMessageReceived is only executed while application is running? Which works on real device and emulator, I receive message, read data payload and show notification and when tap on notifications it opens desired activity, however the thing that does not work is when my application is not running and that is what I want to fix...

Comment: `onMessageReceived` is *always* executed (even when the app is not running) when the FCM *does not contain `notification` payload*. To ensure your app gets the FCM never use the `notification` payload. Use only `data`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec but same code works for the emulator. Notification does show up when app is not running. However I have removed notification payload and did not get notification to show up when app is not running on real device and on emulator. And then I have put notification payload back  it showed up in emulator but still not on the real device

Comment: `remoteMessage.getNotification()` is null when you remove notification payload. Can you post what you tried as UPDATE 2 as well?